# Is there any way to persist a response header in Nginx Plus for subsequent request lookups?

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress

In Nginx Plus acting as a reverse proxy I would like to be able to store the key:value represented by a response header in something like a map. As far as I can see, ngx_http_map_module can't be changed at runtime so I think that's ruled out. What similar storage could I consider?

Comment: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_keyval_module.html#keyval

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like 'keyval' only works in the http context whereas I would need to set the key in the location context based on a request header with the value based on a response header.

Comment: @alexey-ten I've been looking into the keval module you suggested (I think the http context wouldn't be a problem), and it seems that you have to use the API to set values. Do you know if it's possible somehow to set them without using the API?